# Page does not reload after form submit when a file is offered for download

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

On a website there is a form which will send a request to a Java servlet:

```
<form class="export" 
      action="export_data" 
      method="post" 
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"> 
  <input type="image" 
         src="images/btn_export_data.png" 
         name="operation" value="export" />
  <!-- checkboxes of various data exporters -->
</form>
```

The servlet processes the request and offers a file to download. After that I expect the page to reload - but it doesn't. What could be the cause?

---

Things I've tried so far - without success:

**Set a redirect in the servlet**

```
response.sendRedirect( "/content/export_data.jsp" );
```

**Set a forward in the servlet**

```
  // request is the HttpServletRequest
  // response is the HttpServletResponse
  // httpServlet is the HttpServlet
  final HttpSession currentSession = request.getSession();
  final RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher =
        httpServlet.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/content/export_data.jsp" );
  currentSession.setAttribute( "target", "/content/export_data.jsp" );
  requestDispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

**Set the onsubmit event in the page**

```
onsubmit="window.location.reload();"
```

Comment: Try add `onClick` to the button `onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()},100)"`

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: Can you paste the code of servlet?

Comment: Which part are you interested in? The servlet has several thousand lines.

Comment: I'm suprised that the posted forward solution ('set a forward in the servlet') works with all other forms which are part of this webapp but just not with the one which offers a file to download. On the website itself the ``onSubmit`` event seems to be disabled because I can't even raise an alert box with plain JavaScript.